# Approximate meaning of probability?

Tags: probability, self-study, binomial-distribution, normal-approximation

After the football match each football fan leave on the stadium 2 empty bottles. The janitor finds the bottle with probability 0.3. Find the approximate meaning of probability that the janitor collects at least 14/45 of all the bottles left at the stadium after the match if this match visited 6000 fans ?

Also, If anyone can suggest similar level of more problems with the same topics for practice then it will really be a great help. 
I am just confused whether its related to any Limit theorem or how to prepare for such problems?

I am bit confused and irritated too that one of the person has already solved the problem and seems his solution is perfect. If others can't understand/solve then how could you decide problem is incorrect/incomplete? See @bsdfish has already solved this problem with a fine explanation still you guys are saying that problem is unclear? 
I also don't understand the problem this is why I put it here if I know the solution or know the procedure how to go ahead then why do I need to post?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a question from a textbook/exercise? If so, please consider adding [self-stufy](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag.

Comment: I don't know from where this question has been taken but this problem has been asked in my exam. I am also interested to know the name of book if it is taken from any.

Comment: I don't think your question really has to do with the meaning of probability. It seems to be more about want modeling assumptions are required to get specific solutions.  The real controversy bout probability is whether or not we want to look at as subjective where personal prior beliefs enter into deciding what an unknown parameter might be when we considerit ti be random as in the Bayesian approach of Bruno de Finetti.  or the frquentist approach of Kolmogorov and von Mises.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Dear @gung ! I have gone through wiki and let me tell you that neither its a routine question nor its a class test. As I already told in my earlier comment that its a ques asked in my exam that I couldn't answer. I want to prepare my level so that I can solve such questions. I posted this here so that I can get some reference for more such problems and strategy how to go ahead on this. I have studied pdf, limit theorem and all but I am not able to understand this. This is why I posted it here that If any of you could suggest me where I am lacking of and what else  shall I read ?

Comment: @user3076807 I think you don't understand how StackExchange and CrossValidated works. This question was marked as *"unclear"* 19 hours ago. It was like this at that time http://stats.stackexchange.com/revisions/256453/3 . When you post a [tag:self-study] question you must also post what have you tried so far. You didn't. To remove the *"hold"* status, the question goes back to a voting queue. So far your edits haven't changed the question enough to a warrant a reopening. Granted, I think the motif of closure could have been better.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is homework / exam question so I won't give the exact answer but will provide an outline.

In this case, there will be 12000 bottles left at the stadium and for each one, theres an (assumed independent) 0.3 probability that the janitor will find it.  So the distribution of bottles found is $B \sim Binomial(12000, 0.3)$.

Now, you need to figure out how likely the ratio is to be above 14/45.  You can either do that the hard way: either by summing up the PMF or wrangling with the complex CDF or use asymptotics.  Because your variable is the sum of N (12000) independent variables (0/1 Bernoulli in this case), you can use the CLT to approximate your distribution as a Gaussian and use standard Gaussian properties to estimate your quantity.  The mean is pretty clearly 0.3 but what will the variance be?  Once you have the mean and variance, computing the probability that a realization is above 14/45 should be easy.  As a hint, the first step should be computing the variance for a single bottle, $\sim Bernoulli(0.3)$.

Note that once you do the math, the number you'll get is just an approximation because the true distribution isn't exactly Gaussian, just close to it.  For this purposes, this is fine but if you need to bound the quantity for a proof of correctness of an algorithm, you will need something more.

Comment: Can you suggest me some sources from there I can practice such questions and read more about the concept behind this. Though the exam is over but still I would like to have close insight in it.